# Finding a coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am having hard time in calculating (or constructing) $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{\langle y^2 - x^3 - x\rangle}$.

I tried homogenizing the ideal $y^2 - x^3 -x $ to $ wy^2 - x^3 - xw^2$. But from here how to define a morphism into a nice ring such that the ideal goes to kernel.

Comment: Perhaps it’s too late at night for me, but I’m having a lot of trouble understanding your question. What form would an answer satisfactory to you take?

Comment: I mean, $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$ looks like a coordinate ring already.

Comment: @Lubin, I don't like quotient. I want get rid of that. I mean, I want an isomorphic polynomial ring.

Comment: Why does it have to be isomorphic to a polynomial ring?

Comment: @Youngsu, (I need) Only if there is such polynomial ring. (I should have added this earlier)

Comment: It cannot be isomorphic to a polynomial ring because this coordinate ring is not integrally closed and polynomial rings over fields (or UFDs) are.

Comment: @Saurabh, thanks! your comment answers my question.

Comment: @Saurabh, I’m almost sure that this ring *is* integrally closed (in its fraction field).

Comment: The reason that this ring is not a polynomial ring in one variable is that the fraction field is a function-field over $\mathbb C$ of genus one, not genus zero.

Comment: @Lubin You may be right. I thought the ideal was $<y^2-x^3-x^2>$.

Comment: @Saurabh, you’re right on. If the ideal had been the one you mention, the curve would have been a cubic with node, and it’s easy to see that $y/x$ is integral over the ring. In fact, this is a nonsingular cubic (at infinity too!).

Comment: Yes. It certainly is integrally closed, as the variety is smooth.

Answer (score 2):

> The comments under the question suggest that the OP wants to know whether $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{\langle y^2 - x^3 - x\rangle}$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring.

The answer is negative. Assume the contrary and consider $f,g\in\mathbb C[t]$ that correspond to (the residue classes of) $x,y$ in our ring. Then $g^2=f^3+f$. Since $f$ and $g$ can't be both constants we have $\deg f\ge1$ and $\deg g\ge 1$. Let $p\mid f$ be an irreducible polynomial. Write $f=pf_1$ and (necessarily) $g=pg_1$, and thus we get $pg_1^2=f_1(p^2f_1^2+1)$. It follows that $p\mid f_1$, so $f_1=pf_2$ and plugging this into the last equation we get $g_1^2=f_2(p^4f_2^2+1)$. Continuing this way we arrive to an equation of the form $v^2=c(c^2u^4+1)$ with $c\in\mathbb C$, $c\ne0$, and $u,v\in\mathbb C[t]$ of degree $\ge 1$. This is equivalent to $(v-c\sqrt cu^2)(v+c\sqrt cu^2)=c$ and therefore $v\pm c\sqrt cu^2$ are constants, hence $u,v$ are constants, a contradiction.